# How to charge transaction fee in my token insteed of SOL if any one tranfer my XYZ token they pay in XYZ instead SOL, Ithey don't need to hold SOL

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, spl-token-program, token-2022

I'm seeking for help any body can help regarding spl,  token, I'm working on app it has in app wallet, if some did dum task I'll provide my token as mining reward, so what I need that, when they complete his 24 hrs of mine, the get a reward as per there engagement like playing games, but the real question is that, when they get rewards and want to transfer they token to other wallet (i.e. phantom) they don't need to hold the SOL for transfer fee, they just pay the fee in my let's assume token name is XYZ token if they get reward for 20 token(for 24 hrs of gameplay) if he/she withdraw his token let in app wallet named as Wallet A and external wallet(phantom) wallet B he withdraw 20 XYZ token from A to B  he just pay as 1 token for charge he 20-1(trasc fee) he will receive 19 XYZ in wallet B,

In summary what I want if any transfer or transact his token from one wallet to another he paid the fee in XYZ token he don't need to have SOL to pay the fee, for that, if his wallet even don't have a single SOL they just pay the XYZ token as fee instead of SOL

Please help out, how can I get this, I have see an app they do the same, they have in app wallet, users did mining they can able to withdraw there mined token to exchange without having a SOL in app wallet, that app just charge 1 token for first time, and ward they just charge for 0.05 after 1 transfer, so please help me out how xan I achieve this task

Thank for helping in advance

Answer (score 0):

Transaction fees must be paid in SOL on a Solana network, so to perform their transactions, you must either:

- provide SOL to your users to pay for transaction fees
- setup some web service that pays for your user's transactions by signing with one of your keys as the fee payer